# Pinning a delegate within a struct before passing to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, unmanaged

I'm trying to use an unmanaged C dll for loading image data into a C# application. The library has a fairly simple interface where you pass in a struct that contains three callbacks, one to receive the size of the image, one that receives each row of the pixels and finally one called when the load is completed. Like this (C# managed definition):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct st_ImageProtocol
{
   public st_ImageProtocol_done Done;    
   public st_ImageProtocol_setSize SetSize;    
   public st_ImageProtocol_sendLine SendLine;
}
```

The types starting st_ImageProtocol are delgates:

```
public delegate int st_ImageProtocol_sendLine(System.IntPtr localData, int rowNumber, System.IntPtr pixelData);
```

With the test file that I'm using the SetSize should get called once, then the SendLine will get called 200 times (once for each row of pixels in the image), finally the Done callback gets triggered. What actually happens is that the SendLine is called 19 times and then a AccessViolationException is thrown claiming that the library tried to access protected memory.

I have access to the code of the C library (though I can't change the functionality) and during the loop where it calls the SendLine method it does not allocate or free any new memory, so my assumption is that the delegate itself is the issue and I need to pin it before I pass it in (I have no code inside the delegate itself currently, besides a counter to see how often it gets called, so I doubt I'm breaking anything on the managed side). The problem is that I don't know how to do this; the method I've been using to declare the structs in unmanaged space doesn't work with delegates (Marshal.AllocHGlobal()) and I can't find any other suitable method. The delegates themselves are static fields in the Program class so they shouldn't be being garbage collected, but I guess the runtime could be moving them.

[This blog entry by Chris Brumme](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/05/06/51385.aspx) says that delegates don't need to be pinned before being passed into unmanaged code:

> Clearly the unmanaged function pointer must refer to a fixed address.  It would be a disaster if the GC were relocating that!  This leads many applications to create a pinning handle for the delegate.  This is completely unnecessary.  The unmanaged function pointer actually refers to a native code stub that we dynamically generate to perform the transition & marshaling.  This stub exists in fixed memory outside of the GC heap.

But I don't know if this holds true when the delegate is part of a struct. It does imply that it is possible to manually pin them though, and I'm interested in how to do this or any better suggestions as to why a loop would run 19 times then suddenly fail.

Thanks.

---

Edited to answer Johan's questions...

The code that allocates the struct is as follows:

```
_sendLineFunc = new st_ImageProtocol_sendLine(protocolSendLineStub);

_imageProtocol = new st_ImageProtocol()
                     {
                          //Set some other properties...
                          SendLine = _sendLineFunc
                     };

int protocolSize = Marshal.SizeOf(_imageProtocol);
_imageProtocolPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(protocolSize);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(_imageProtocol, _imageProtocolPtr, true);
```

Where the _sendLineFunc and the _imageProtocol variables are both static fields of the Program class. If I understand the internals of this correctly, that means that I'm passing an unmanaged pointer to a *copy* of the _imageProtocol variable into the C library, but that copy contains a reference to the static _sendLineFunc. This should mean that the copy isn't touched by the GC - since it is unmanaged - and the delegate won't be collected since it is still in scope (static).

The struct actually gets passed to the library as a return value from another callback, but as a pointer:

```
private static IntPtr beginCallback(IntPtr localData, en_ImageType imageType)
{
    return _imageProtocolPtr;
}
```

Basically there is another struct type that holds the image filename and the function pointer to this callback, the library figures out what type of image is stored in the file and uses this callback to request the correct protocol struct for the given type. My filename struct is declared and managed in the same way as the protocol one above, so probably contains the same mistakes, but since this delegate is only called once and called quickly I haven't had any problems with it yet.

---

Edited to update

Thanks to everybody for their responses, but after spending another couple of days on the problem and making no progress I decided to shelve it. In case anyone is interested I was attempting write a tool for users of the Lightwave 3D rendering application and a nice feature would have been the ability to view all the different image formats that Lightwave supports (some of which are fairly exotic). I thought that the best way to do this would be to write a C# wrapper for the plugin architecture that Lightwave uses for image manipulation so I could use their code to actually load the files. Unfortunately after trying a number of the plugins against my solution I had a variety of errors that I couldn't understand or fix and my guess is that Lightwave doesn't call the methods on the plugins in a standard way, probably to improve the security of running external code (wild stab in the dark, I admit). For the time being I'm going to drop the image feature and if I do decide to reinstate it I'll approach it in a different way.

Thanks again, I learnt a lot through this process even though I didn't get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when registering a callback delegate (it would be called, then poof!).  My problem was that the object with the method being delegated was getting GC'ed. I created the object in a more global place so as to keep it from being GC'ed.

If something like that doesn't work, here are some other things to look at:

As additional info, take a look at [GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx) from the Marshal class.  That is another way you could do this.  Just make sure that the delegates are not GC'ed.  Then, instead of delegates in your struct, declare them as IntPtr.

That may not solve the pinning, but take a look at [`fixed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(VS.80).aspx) keyword, even though that may not work for you since you are dealing with a longer lifetime than for what that is typically used.

Finally, look at [`stackalloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4(VS.80).aspx) for creating non-GC memory.  These methods will require the use of `unsafe`, and might therefore put some other constraints on your Assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know a little more:

- How do you create the ImageProtocol struct? Is it a local variable or a class member or do you allocate it in unmanaged memory with Marshal.AllocHGlobal?
- How is it sent to the C function? Directly as stack variable or as a pointer?

---

A really tricky problem! It feels like the delegate data is moved around by the GC which causes the access violation. The interesting thing is that the delegate data type is a reference data type, which stores its data on the GC heap. This data contains things like the address of the function to call (function pointer) but also a reference to the object that contains the function. This should mean that even though the actual function code is stored outside of the GC heap, the data that holds the function pointer is stored in the GC heap and can hence be moved by the GC. I thought about the problem a lot last night but haven't come up with a solution....

Comment: Thanks for the questions - I've edited my question with some more details

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly how the callback is declared in the C library.  Unless it is explictly declared `__stdcall` you'll slowly corrupt your stack.  You'll see your method get called (probably with the parameters reversed) but at some point in the future the program will crash.

So far as I know there is no way around that, other than writing another callback function in C that sits between the C# code and the library that wants a `__cdecl` callback.

Answer (score 0):

If the c function is a __cdecl function then you have to use the Attribut
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
before the delegate declaration.