# C# How to Pinvoke callbacks in a struct

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am working with a 3. party SDK, which is made up from .dll, .lib and .h files. I am using the .dll's to PInvoke against. And the .h files to see the function names and parameters. (So I am not using the .lib files).

The SDK is rather complex, so making the PInvoke wrappers have proven to be a challenge. All the functions/structs/enums is defined in the .h files.

I am parsing a struct to the unmanaged C code, and the struct contains 2 delegates, which the unmanaged C code calls.

I am creating the struct in C#, and both delegates are set in C#.

I get a 'System.AccessViolationException' when I call it.

**Use**

```
//C#
private CallBackInterface callBack;

public void MyMethod()
{
    callBack = new CallBackInterface ();
    callBack.event1 = new CallBackInterface.event1_delegate(event1_Handler);
    callBack.event2 = new CallBackInterface.event2_delegate(event2_Handler);
    CallBackFunction(ref callBack); //Throws a 'System.AccessViolationException' 

}  

public int event1_Handler(IntPtr Inst, uint type, uint timeMs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got a callback on event 1!");
    return 0;
}

public int event2_Handler(IntPtr Inst, out LH_BOOL Continue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got a callback on event 2!");
    Continue = LH_BOOL.TRUE;
    return 0;
}
```

**Function: CallBackFunction**

```
//C 
ERROR CallBackFunction(CallBackInterface  * callBack);

//C#
[DllImport("myDll.dll", EntryPoint = "CallBackFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern ERROR CallBackFunction(ref CallBackInterface callBack);
```

**Struct: CallBackInterface**

```
//C 
typedef unsigned long LH_TIME;
typedef struct CallBackInterface_S{
    int (*event1) (void* inst, unsigned long type, LH_TIME timeMs);
    int (*event2) (void* inst, LH_BOOL* Continue); //continue should be set to tell the unmanaged c code if it should continue or stop.
} CallBackInterface;

//C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CallBackInterface
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int event1_delegate(IntPtr inst, uint type, uint timeMs);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int event2_delegate(IntPtr inst, out LH_BOOL Continue);

    public event1_delegate event1;
    public event2_delegate event2;
}
```

**Enum: LH_BOOL**

```
//C Enum: LH_BOOL
typedef enum LH_BOOL_E {
    FALSE= 0, 
    TRUE = 1, 
 } LH_BOOL;

 //C# Enum: LH_BOOL
 public enum LH_BOOL
 {
   FALSE= 0, 
   TRUE = 1, 
 }
```

**Enum: ERROR**

```
//C Enum: ERROR 
typedef enum ERROR_E {
    OK = 0, //Everything is ok
    E_ARG = 1, //Error in the Arguments 
    E_DATA = 2 //Data error
    //And more...
 } ERROR;

 //C# Enum: ERROR
 public enum ERROR
 {
    OK = 0, //Everything is ok
    E_ARG = 1, //Error in the Arguments 
    E_DATA = 2 //Data error
    //And more...
 }
```

Comment: Do you know if the exception happens on the initial call, or when one of the callbacks happens?  If the latter, do you know which callback it is?

Comment: I do not have access to the C code, I only have access to the .dlls. So I don't know when in the C code the problem occurs. But I would expect it is when trying to call my C# functions.

Comment: i have the same problem now. and really hope someone figured it out already !

Comment: @Koby I have a solution now, I will see if I can make a full explanation of what I did in a few days. The short story is I had an error in the CallBackInterface: "public delegate int event2_delegate(IntPtr inst, out LH_BOOL Continue);" should be "public delegate int event2_delegate(IntPtr inst, ref LH_BOOL Continue);". You have to be very carefull when using "ref" and "out", magic happens in C#, it works better by allocating the whole struct to the memory yourself using the "Marshal" class, and then just pass in a pointer to your 3. party .dll, but this solution requires more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser is, I had a problem in my CallBackInterface, I had:

```
public delegate int event2_delegate(IntPtr inst, out LH_BOOL Continue);
```

This should have been

```
public delegate int event2_delegate(IntPtr inst, ref LH_BOOL Continue);
```

The reason is the 3. party allocates the LH_BOOL Continue in memory, which I then have to set the correct value for. But using "out" means C# will allocate the value, and when the 3. party tries to set it, it tries to set a value it does not have access to. "ref" solves this by allowing for an existing value to be passed in as a argument.

So the final code looks like this:

**Use**

```
//C#
private CallBackInterface callBack;


public void MyMethod()
{
    callBack = new CallBackInterface ();
    callBack.event1 = new CallBackInterface.event1_delegate(event1_Handler);
    callBack.event2 = new CallBackInterface.event2_delegate(event2_Handler);
    CallBackFunction(ref callBack); 

}  

 public int event1_Handler(IntPtr Inst, uint type, uint timeMs)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Got a callback on event 1!");
     return 0;
 }

 public int event2_Handler(IntPtr Inst, out LH_BOOL Continue)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Got a callback on event 2!");
     Continue = LH_BOOL.TRUE;
     return 0;
 }
```

**Function: CallBackFunction**

```
//C 
ERROR CallBackFunction(CallBackInterface  * callBack);

//C#
[DllImport("myDll.dll", EntryPoint = "CallBackFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern ERROR CallBackFunction(ref CallBackInterface callBack);
```

**Struct: CallBackInterface**

```
//C 
typedef unsigned long LH_TIME;
typedef struct CallBackInterface_S{
    int (*event1) (void* inst, unsigned long type, LH_TIME timeMs);
    int (*event2) (void* inst, LH_BOOL* Continue); //continue should be set to tell the unmanaged c code if it should continue or stop.
} CallBackInterface;

//C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CallBackInterface
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int event1_delegate(IntPtr inst, uint type, uint timeMs);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int event2_delegate(IntPtr inst, ref LH_BOOL Continue);

    public event1_delegate event1;
    public event2_delegate event2;
}
```

**Enum: LH_BOOL**

```
//C Enum: LH_BOOL
typedef enum LH_BOOL_E {
    FALSE= 0, 
    TRUE = 1, 
 } LH_BOOL;

 //C# Enum: LH_BOOL
 public enum LH_BOOL
 {
   FALSE= 0, 
   TRUE = 1, 
 }
```

**Enum: ERROR**

```
//C Enum: ERROR 
typedef enum ERROR_E {
    OK = 0, //Everything is ok
    E_ARG = 1, //Error in the Arguments 
    E_DATA = 2 //Data error
    //And more...
 } ERROR;

 //C# Enum: ERROR
 public enum ERROR
 {
    OK = 0, //Everything is ok
    E_ARG = 1, //Error in the Arguments 
    E_DATA = 2 //Data error
    //And more...
 }
```

---

While working with PInvoke, I have grown happy to use IntPtr as both input and output of functions. The benefit is C# won't make any restrictions, the challenge is to get it correct and it requires a extra bunch of work. 
To be able to get it correct it requires the functions you call are well documented, so you know exactly how the input and output should look like in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks are likely to be cdecl, but I would be more doubtful about this:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll", EntryPoint = "CallBackFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern ERROR CallBackFunction(ref CallBackInterface callBack);
```

Have you tried it like this (the EntryPoint is redundant if you're not trying to have a different name in C++ to C#, and stdcall is the default calling convention for DllImport, and the usual one for DLL exports):

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
public static extern ERROR CallBackFunction(ref CallBackInterface callBack);
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.  stdcall is a Windows thing, not a C++ thing.   (Actually, it's perhaps a Pascal thing, but that's ancient history)

Comment: But changing it to [DllImport("myDll.dll")] does not help sadly.

Comment: I have tested another function call to the .dll, where I pass in a delegate, and that one works without a problem.

Comment: Do you expect to get a callback before 'CallbackFunction' actually returns?  I would have thought it more likely that they'd be using callbacks to call back at some later time, in which case you do have to start to be careful about object lifetime and pinning, etc.

Comment: Because of the lifetime issue I have made "private CallBackInterface callBack;" So as long as the class doesn't cleaned up, the CallBack shouldn't be cleaned up either. But I do expect a callback before the Pinvoked CallBackFunction returns.

Comment: Have still not found any solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720750/pinning-a-delegate-within-a-struct-before-passing-to-unmanaged-code Seems to have had the same problem, but didn't find a solution.

Comment: @Mr.JavaWolf I am out of ideas - obviously I can't build your code here, and I think my next steps would involve detailed debugging/disassembly to see what's actually going on when things crash.  I can't really help with that via SO...